# css and image imports not working with spring boot in intellij

Tags: html, spring-boot

My CSS and Image imports for spring boot project are not working. I am trying to figure it out from very long time but its simply not working, in some of my previous eclipse projects I remember i had no problems but recently I started working with intelliJ community version and i am not able to make it work.

Environment:

[image]

So in the above image I am trying to import css and image in my html login page, but i get following error:

> Refused to apply style from
>   'http://localhost:63342/weather_api/templates/css/login-register-style.css'
>   because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME
>   type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. login.html:21
>
> GET http://localhost:63342/images/face.png 404 (Not Found)

The problem is coming from two files marked by red in above image.

**What I tried:**

I also tried using Thymleaf tag to add css file but its also not working. However when i put these files directly in `templates` folder they all work fine. But i want to refactor my code and not mix all files in one folder.

Would be glad if someone can help me out of this. thank you.

**EDIT**

The `static` folder in the workspace i have manually created in by default created resource folder. Similarly the `templates` i manually created after project was generated, however all the files under templates are executed. the only problem exist is with contents under `static` folder

Comment: Try removing the forward slashes in "css" and "image" src paths. (e.g - `src="images/face.png"`)

Comment: Also, if you look at the error `http://localhost:63342/weather_api/templates/css/login-register-style.css` it has a `templates` directory in it. Check why this is happening. Since you have a URL issue and does not know how the application is handling the urls, one way to figure this out would be to check it on the browser if the file is accessible using different URLs

Comment: yes. i solved it last night. you are right about your first comment. forward slashes was the problem. now its all working fine. thanks

Comment: Oh cool, I added that as the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the forward slashes in "css" and "image" src paths. (e.g - src="images/face.png")